# Есть ли простая Net библиотека для симуляции взаимодействия физических объектов?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли простая Net библиотека для симуляции взаимодействия физических объектов ?
Вот пример того что я хочу сделать https://www.youtube.com/shorts/aLd7ymRgd-M 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Конечно я могу использовать любой игровой движок который поддерживает C#, но мне кажется это избыточным.
Мб есть что то максимально простое?

Comment: https://github.com/codingben/box2d-netstandard

Comment: Для такого физический движок не нужен, всё должно свестись к несложным математическим формулам (самым сложным будет наверно посчитать угол отражения, но сверхразум для этого не требуется)

Comment: Ну в общем да, [вот эта формула](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13263) это по сути и есть вся физика здесь. Ну и ещё гравитацию применить, но это уже мелочи

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/parallel-programming-winforms-raytracer-cs/ покопайтесь в этом примере, там 3д, но вся векторная математика трассировки лучей в софтварном варианте есть. Ускорение свободного падения только рассчитать, и всё.

Comment: @aepot чёт вас куда-то слишком далеко унесло по-моему

Comment: @andreymal я подробнейшим образом ковырял тот проект, там есть вся математика векторная по отражениям. Из 3Д в 2Д переделать легче лёгкого.

Comment: @aepot наверное вам сюда) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1564495