# Отражение луча от шара

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, любой-язык

Есть координаты шары, его радиус, координаты луча (на границе шара), и его направление. Как луч отразится от шара?

Comment: Угол падения равен углу отражения.

Comment: "Угол падения равен углу отражения". Ищите точку первого пересечения луча со сферой, строите отражённый луч. Там прикольная геометрия, рекомендую сделать самому - понравится. Будут конкретные вопросы - спрашивайте.

Answer (score 6):

Если под выражением "на границе шара" вы имеете ввиду, что он касается шара, то он продолжит свое движение (рис. 1).

Если луч не касается шара, то он отразится от точки касания под углом, равным углу падения, относительно касательной, проходящей, через эту точку (рис. 2).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Картинки 1 и 2 - одно и то же. Угол падения равен углу отражения что в том, что в другом случае.

Comment: По факту да. Но я просто показал как поведёт себя луч при касании, потому что не понял, что автор вопроса подразумевает под выражением "на границе шара".